# Is it possible to get the main level of subdivision of a country using google places API?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

Is it possible to get the main level of subdivision of a country using google places API? By subdivisions, I mean, for example, in the country of Uruguay obtaining its 19 departments or, for example, in the country of Mexico, obtaining its 31 states + the federal district. I'm getting these subdivision numbers from this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2)

In order to achieve this I am first trying the Autocomplete service in this way

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json\?input\=Spain\&types\=\(regions\)\&components\=country:es\&key\=API-KEY
```

But here I have the following problems, first the number of results that a query returns using autocomplete that is limited to 5 according to the documentation, the other drawback is the types parameter that as far as I understand allows me to use (regions) that contains administrative_area_level_1 and administrative_area_level_2, here I would prefer to use administrative_area_level_1

And the Place Search in this way

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json\?query\=spain\&type\=administrative_area_level_1\&key\=API-KEY
```

here I generally do not get results ZERO_RESULTS status, and in the countries where I occasionally find results are incomplete for example Nicaragua returns 9 results, but must be 15 departments and 2 autonomous regions

About the type administrative_area_level_1 I read in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Types)

> Not all nations exhibit these administrative levels

What I described above is what I have tried, I thank you if you can give me your comments on whether this possible

Comment: Maps API cannot be used for everything. Why not use a dedicated API / web service?

Comment: I understand. The root of the task I work on is to see the possibility of migrating from a service to google places API, early in this process I identify this case and try to know if it is possible to do it with just google places API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that it is currently **not** supported for the Google Places API to show an exhaustive list of addresses by a certain filter such as by country.

Places Autocomplete is designed to return place predictions based on the user input and perceived relevance. While Place Searches like Text Search returns information about a set of places that matches a given string.

There is also a related feature request for this functionality, it's marked as Infeasible/Intended behavior but you can still star it to receive updates:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64769088

If you are interested to have this feature, you may also file this as feature request in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/maps/support/#issue_tracker).

Comment: Thanks Angela, I imagined this would be the answer but I had to ask. Thanks for the links. For now to achieve this I use geonames by consulting the geoname and hierarchy tables as follows `SELECT g.name, concat_ws(',', g.latitude, g.longitude) AS latlgn
FROM geonames.geoname AS g
INNER JOIN geonames.hierarchy AS h ON g.geonameid = h.childId AND h.parentId = '2510769' AND h.type = "ADM"` in this example 2510769 corresponds to the geonameid of Spain, and in my case I need to obtain the name of the administrative divisions along with their coordinate